# Modal visibility not updated within ListView

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native, modal-dialog

I have a bunch of products which I render via a ListView component. Some products need more config i.e. size so when a user clicks add to cart button I intend to display a size selection within a modal.

```
<ListView
dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
renderRow={rowData => (
    <View>
          ...
          <Modal
               transparent={false}
               visible={this.state.visibleModal}
               onRequestClose={() => { this.setState({visible: false})}
          >
              ....
          </Modal>

    </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the state variable `visible` but using the state variable `visibleModal` to set the visibility

```
<Modal
  transparent={ false }
  visible={ this.state.visibleModal }
  onRequestClose={ () => { this.setState({ visibleModal: false }) }
>
...
</Modal>
```